# Construction of lines through a given point, cutting two given circles in congruent chords

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Given a point $P$ and two circles $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ with centers $O$ and $O'$. I'm searching for a method to construct lines passing through $P$ and defining on each circle chords of same length.

A geometer professor made the following drawing to illustrate the problem.

[image]

Many thanks for any constructive idea or suggestions.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem (I'm not nearly as good in geometry as the other people of this site), but I think the concept of radical axis is useful. As we get tangents of equal length from the points on that line.

Comment: Thank you Aaratrick ! You're right the radical axis play an essential role but in this problem,  the point $P$ is everywhere (not only on the radical axis).

Comment: Where is the point P?

Comment: @Moti I suppose that P is anywhere outside the two circles

Comment: Yes, the point P can be anywhere. Suppose the two circles are secant. If $P$ is on the radical axis, two lines are solutions. One of them is the radical axis itself. In general, the problem has 0, 1 or 2 solutions.

Comment: @beginarray: Your comments suggest that you know more about this question than the problem statement alone indicates. Please always include as much information as you have, to help people avoid wasting time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already know. Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3598227/edit) to add details to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_1$ and $R_1$ the radii of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma '$ respectively, and $w$ the length of the desired chord.

Construct two circles $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda '$ concentric to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma '$ with radii $r$ and $R$ respectively, so that:
$$r = \sqrt{r_1^2-(\frac{w}{2})^2} \quad \quad (1)$$ 
and
$$R = \sqrt{R_1^2-(\frac{w}{2})^2}\quad \quad (2)$$
Let $OP=d$, $O'P=D$,and $OO'=L$.

Let $PS$ the height of $\triangle POO'$ relative to side $OO'$, and let's call $PS=H$ and $O'S=\delta$ for short.
We have:

$$\delta = \frac{D^2-d^2+L^2}{2L} \quad \quad (3)$$

and

$$H^2 = D^2 - \delta^2 \quad \quad (4)$$

The value of $w$, so that P is a point of the secant lines that does not cross the segment $OO'$, can be found solving equations (1), (2), (3), (4) e (5).

$$\frac{LR}{R-r} -\delta = \sqrt{(\frac{HL} {R-r})^2-R^2} \quad \quad (5)$$

That value of $w$ makes the two secant lines relative to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma '$ be also tangent lines of $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda '$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose first that the two circles intersect each other. Let $F$ be the midpoint of the line of centres $O_1O_2$, and let $F'$ be the reflection of $F$ in the radical axis $\mathcal{R}$ of the two circles. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the parabola with focus $F$ and directrix the line through $F'$ parallel to the radical axis $\mathcal{R}$. If $\ell$ is a line, let $X_\ell$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $F$ to $\ell$. Then $\ell$ is a tangent to $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if $X_\ell$ lies on the radical axis.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBEna.jpg)

Given a point $P$, suppose that $\ell$ is a tangent to $\mathcal{P}$ that passes through $P$. Let $M_1$, $M_2$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $O_1$, $O_2$ to the line $\ell$. The lines $O_1M_1$, $FX_\ell$, $O_2M_2$ are parallel, and $F$ is the midpoint of $O_1O_2$, and hence $X_\ell$ is the midpoint of $M_1M_2$. If this line $\ell$ intersects the two circles, forming chords of lengths $w_1$, $w_2$ respectively (and midpoints $M_1$, $M_2$), then the Intersecting Chords Theorem tells us that

$$ X_\ell M_1^2 - \frac14w_1^2 \; = \; X_\ell A \times X_\ell B \; = \; X_\ell M_2^2 - \frac14w_2^2 $$

where the radical axis meets the two circles at $A$ and $B$, and hence $w_1=w_2$.

Start with a point $P$ outside the parabola $\mathcal{P}$, and draw a circle with $FP$ as diameter. Since $P$ lies outside the parabola $\mathcal{P}$, this circle will intersect the radical axis $\mathcal{R}$ at two points $X_1$, $X_2$. The lines $PX_1$, $PX_2$ will be tangents to $\mathcal{P}$; if the lines intersect both circles, they will cut the circles in congruent chords with midpoints $M_{1,1},M_{2,1}$ and $M_{1,2},M_{2,2}$ respectively.

It is easy to show that the mutual tangents to the two circles, which pass through the external similitude centre $Se$ of the circles, are themselves tangents to $\mathcal{P}$. It is clear that the line $PX_1$ will not intersect the two circles if $P$ lies above the upper mutual tangent, and that $PX_2$ will not intersect the two circles if $P$ lies below the lower mutual tangent.

For us to be able to perform this construction, therefore, $P$ must lie outside the parabola $\mathcal{P}$ (so that the points $X_1,X_2$ exist) and also $P$ must lie outside the wedge formed by the two mutual tangents to the circles vertically opposite to $\mathcal{P}$.

If the two circles do not intersect, the basic construction remains the same, but the allowed region for $P$ is further limited. Consideration also needs to be made of where $P$ lies in relation two the two mutual tangents to the circle that meet at their internal similitude centre.